# Update with leftjoin requires to join the update table itself

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I want to update a table with values from another table, which not always exist. So I need to left join the other table. The only way I found is this:

```
UPDATE lessonentity update
SET title=a.test
FROM lessonentity l
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'hoho1' test) a ON(true)
where l.lessonid=48552
AND update.lessonid=l.lessonid
```

My question: Is it possible to left-join another table, without inner-joining (where) the updating-table again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not using an explicit `join`.  In your case, this is sufficient given that `a` has only one row:

```
UPDATE lessonentity le
    SET title = a.test
    FROM (SELECT 'hoho1' test) a
    WHERE le.lessonid = 48552;
```

Normally, there would be an additional condition in the `WHERE`, connecting `a` and `le`, but that is not necessary in this case because the table has a single row.

Comment: this would not update anything when the table a is empty... i want to set null if the row in a does not exist